# How to take multiple key input in wxwidgets?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

As I am making a game in Wxwidgets. The place where i am stuck is to jump Mario and take the input when the Mario is jumping in the air. Let me make you clear - When an player press space to jump vertical 
the loop to jump Mario will run but when the player presses the "d" key to move forward while jumping it should jump forward.... i also need your help to take two input at the same time like in game when we press shift and "w" the player will walk faster but when we press only "w" key the player will walk slow..

```
void MyFrame :: OnChar(wxKeyEvent& event){
     wxChar  uc = event.GetUnicodeKey();
           switch ( uc )
         {
             case 97:
                        tempx = x;
                        x = x - 5;
                        Check(x);
                        FindGround(x);
                        CheckForNextMove(x,y,CurrentGroundX,CurrentGroundY,PreviousGroundX,PreviousGroundY,NextGroundX,NextGroundY);
                        Refresh();
                        break;
             case 100:
                        tempx =x;
                        x = x + 5;
                        Check(x);
                        FindGround(x);
                        CheckForNextMove(x,y,CurrentGroundX,CurrentGroundY,PreviousGroundX,PreviousGroundY,NextGroundX,NextGroundY);
                        Refresh();
                        break;
            case 32:
            tempy = y;
                for(int i=0;i<=10;i++){
                    check = true;
                    tempx = x;
                    Sleep(1);
                        y=y-7;
                        x=x+5;
                        Check(x);
                        FindGround(x);
                        CheckForNextMove(x,y,CurrentGroundX,CurrentGroundY,PreviousGroundX,PreviousGroundY,NextGroundX,NextGroundY);
                        Update();
                        Refresh();
                                              }
                for(int j=0;j<=10;j++){
                    check = true;
                    tempx = x;
                    Sleep(1);
                        y=y+7;
                        x=x+5;
                        Check(x);
                        FindGround(x);
                        CheckForNextMove(x,y,CurrentGroundX,CurrentGroundY,PreviousGroundX,PreviousGroundY,NextGroundX,NextGroundY);
                        Update();
                        Refresh();
                        if(stop){ stop = false; break; }
                                              }
                        check = false;
                        Update();
                        Refresh();
                        break;
 }
event.Skip();
}
```

here is the code where pressing space bar will make mario to jump in parabolic path but i wanted to make it more professional. I want mario to jump in parabolic when we press two key at the same time i.e. (when I press vertical jump key and right motion key then it will have to jump in right direction in parabolic path.

Comment: How can we help you without seeing your code? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @NervousHero, also it would be nice to know which game engine you are using.

Comment: i am not using any game engine... i new to game development so i am little bit confuse while making mario as my first game project

Comment: @NervousHero, keyboard events are processed one by one, so when you press <SpaceBar> that key will be handled. And if you press "UpArrow" that key will be handled. You really should be looking at one of the game engines and start using it.

Comment: The game engine will be able to handle 2 and sometimes 3 key presses at the same time, not just a "Ctrl"/"Alt"/"Shift" + <Key> combination. Also it will help you make sprite movement much smoother. Just google "game engine for beginner"

Comment: Basically, don't run secondary loops inside your event handlers that block the main game loop. Keep note of state changes and let the main game loop apply them as needed. For instance, when the user presses down the `Space` key, take note of that and let your main game loop update the current drawing on subsequent loop iterations until the jump is complete. If the user presses down the `D` key, take note that of that and let the main game loop move the current drawing sideways on subsequent loop iterations as needed. This way, if both keys are down at the same time, they get applied together.

Comment: @RemyLebeau can please explain me with some code so it will be clear for me to implement what you've said plzzz.

Comment: @Igor As we were planning to make our own game engine for making this game but don't have enough time to do so as our board exam is near so can we do with this only do you have any idea...(by using idle event can't we do)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your program control flow to only remember that a key was pressed or released in `wxEVT_KEY_{DOWN,UP}` handlers instead of trying to do everything in `wxEVT_CHAR` handler.

Also, you definitely shouldn't ever have any calls to `Sleep()` or long-running loops in the event handlers, so whenever you think about putting them there, you can be sure that you're doing something wrong.